# Compilation of 2 libraries from the same code base

Tags: gcc, embedded

For an embedded application, I need to have 2 libraries compiled from the same code base - only with different compilation flags - stored in NV RAM. At run (or load) time, I plan to have a single entry point where the relevant library would be selected (loaded / executed).

Since there's a single entry point, and to avoid complexity, I would like to keep static linking. However, for that I need to distinguish between the symbols of each library from the other.

I am using GCC as toolchain.
How is it possible to 'intervene' with the compile / link process to add - for example - a different prefix to symbols of each library, that would be used by the linker?
Alternatively, could you help by proposing another method to achieve what I need?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? For now it's a bit obscure what do you intend to achieve.

Comment: I have made some progress and found out about `objcopy` utility. 
`--redefine-sym old=new--redefine-syms=filename`
Looks like I could create one library with symbols having _prefix1_<symbol> and the other library with symbols having _prefix2_<symbol>.  
Then there should not be any direct call to one of the symbols from the shared code as these symbols will no longer be exported.
Still need to find a convenient way to redefine all the exported symbols without going one by one (there are 1000s). 
In response to @Akira

Answer (score 0):

There is a good way of doing that. Naturally, in your main code at run-time you want to avoid any decision what library to use, so any decision making at run-time is a very bad design chose. Using all kind of crap like function pointers and #ifdef in reference to a different static libraries make the code unmaintainable, unreadable and not scale-able.

So, one of the right way of doing that is to use dynamic binding of your library + independent interface (abstraction level) as a static library. And whenever your interface is initialized it decides what dll to load. Thus, you put logic behind what lib to use into the right place into corresponding abstraction layer.

```
//           main code
//               |
//          lib_proxy.lib (static)
//           /       \ 
//      lib1.dll   lib2.dll (dynamic)
```

NB (opinion): Another way, of course, is to use different build scripts, but it was proven many times, at least for me, that it's one of the best way to clusterfuck the entire project.